# What encoding does Outlook use for plain text messages?

Tags: unicode, outlook, decode, plaintext, email

I need to decode e-mails saved from Outlook as Text Only. Unfortunately they're not in plain ISO-8859-1 since they contain special "smart quote" characters. Does the codepage used by Outlook have a real name (that I can pass to unicode.decode() in Python) or is it just some arbitrary made-up nonsense which I'll have to manually decode? And if so, does anyone have a reference for all the "special" characters Microsoft added?

Comment: It's not standard UTF-8? (I assume you've already tried that?) I'm also not convinced this is truly programming-related.

Comment: When did Microsoft start using UTF-8 for anything? I believe they still call UTF-16 simply “Unicode”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite likely that Outlook will save messages in your current locale. My guess would be Windows-1252.

Nitpick: What you call “smart quotes” is actually the way quotes are supposed to look. The quotes you've been using in your post are known as “typewriter quotes”; for mechanic typewriters, the number of keys was a major cost factor and quotes, which look very similar to one another, and the inch symbol were coalesced into a single key, aesthetics be damned.

Comment: That's "cp1252" in Python by the way.

Answer (score 1):

There are many (locale-dependent) [Windows code pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page), so maybe worst-case it depends on the country in which the sender resides.

Comment: I can assume that all messages will be from US or UK English locales. It looks like Windows-1252 is the right encoding actually, thanks.